# error in 301 permanent redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

i am using htaccess for 301 permanent redirect.
i have to make a redirect for bima.php to ge.php.so i wrote the below code in htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^bima.php?$ $1/ge.php [NC,R=301,L]
```

this works properly..whenever i put www.test.com/bima.php in url it will redirect to www.test.com/ge.php
the problem is i have to do a 301 redirect for ge.php also.that means whenever www.test.com/gen.php in url it will redirect to www.test.com/bima.php.
www.test.com/bima.php needs to redirect to www.test.com/gen.php and vice versa.
Any idea?or anyway to do this?

Comment: about the two ge.php and gen.php? is this a typo and you are using two files in fact (including bima.php) or this is a system with 3 files?

Comment: Obviously, we all agree this is an infinite loop. Is the goal to reverse the two, so that going to bima.php redirects to ge.php (and then stops) and going to ge.php redirects to bima.php (and then stops)? So basically (if 1 redirect 2 HALT; if 2 redirect 1 HALT)?

Comment: Is there ever a situation where the person correctly goes to the URL on the first try?  If not, then I think you've outsmarted yourself. How will the server/browser/client ever know it has actually successfully reached the right URL?  If you simply want the content of ge.php to load when they go to bima.php, `Alias` might be a better solution. With redirect, you are actually sending the directive to the browser to go to send a new request to the new URL, hence the loop (since Apache sees it as a new request).

Comment: an env var might help. Check my answer. It may cause other issues though, so heed any warnings attached to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your redirect rule

```
RewriteRule ^bima.php?$ $1/ge.php [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^ge.php?$ $1/bima.php [NC,R=301,L]
```

Is redirecting in infinite loop. Remove one of them.

No matter what type of logic you use, the redirection you are attempting will end of in loop at one time. So better avoid the need of such requirement.

---

*Here is a PHP Solution*

**File:** *ge.php*

```
if($_SESSION['redirected']['from'] != 'bima.php') {
   header("location: bima.php");
   $_SESSION['redirected']['from'] = 'ge.php';
   exit;
}
```

**File:** *bima.php*

```
if($_SESSION['redirected']['from'] != 'ge.php') {
   header("location: ge.php");
   $_SESSION['redirected']['from'] = 'ge.php';
   exit;
}
```

Comment: i have to redirect bima.php to ge.php and ge.php to bima.php.how can?

Comment: @asitha, I can code an ugly solution for this, but please rethink, as this is not a SOLUTION you are looking for.

Comment: @Starx - Would my solution work beyond the first request? What I mean is, would it redirect for x -> y but then fail for y -> x?

Answer (score 0):

`bima.php` redirects to `ge.php` and `ge.php` to `bima.php`. This will cause an endless loop. What are you trying to achieve? Why do you want `ge.php` redirect to `bima.php` and vice-versa?

You should change your design either way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, though I agree with everyone that the basic concept is a bit wacky:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:redirected} !=1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^bima.php?$ $1/ge.php [E=redirected:1,NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^ge.php?$ $1/bima.php [E=redirected:1,NC,R=301,L]
```

By setting the environment variable with the redirect, the second redirect won't trigger, as it will see the redirected rule has been set.  Not sure if this will screw up redirects after the initial success, however. Someone else know?

Comment: bummer. Maybe the env gets reset because of the `L` flag. In Apache 2.0 and earlier, there is a a MaxRedirects option, and in 2.4 there is an `END` flag, but I'm not seeing any equivalent between 2.2.

Comment: @Anthony, Using a common environment variable `redirect` there isn't anyway to identify the source of redirection, so redirection will stop from the second time.

Comment: @Starx - But it's not `redirect`, it's `redirected`. If it was `has-redirected` would that work? Or are you saying that the because the env var is the same in both cases, the second time will fail, as I originally suspected? Obviously having two env vars only recreates the original issue.

Comment: @Anthony, Yes, I meant due to same enviroment variable.